# Speeding up the light processing of ~50GB CSV file

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas, optimization

I have a ~50GB csv file with which I have to

- Take several subsets of the columns of the CSV
- Apply a different format string specification to each subset of columns of the CSV.
- Output a new CSV for each subset with its own format specification.

I opted to use Pandas, and have a general approach of iterating over chunks of a handy chunk-size (of just over half a million lines) to produce a DataFrame, and appending the chunk to each output CSV. So something like this:

```
_chunk_size = 630100

column_mapping = {
    'first_output_specification' : ['Scen', 'MS', 'Time', 'CCF2', 'ESW10'],
    # ..... similar mappings for rest of output specifications
}
union_of_used_cols = ['Scen', 'MS', 'Time', 'CCF1', 'CCF2', 'VS', 'ESW 0.00397', 'ESW0.08',
                    'ESW0.25', 'ESW1', 'ESW 2', 'ESW3', 'ESW 5', 'ESW7', 'ESW 10', 'ESW12',
                    'ESW 15', 'ESW18', 'ESW 20', 'ESW22', 'ESW 25', 'ESW30', 'ESW 35', 
                    'ESW40']

chnk_iter = pd.read_csv('my_big_csv.csv', header=0, index_col=False,
                        iterator=True, na_filter=False, usecols=union_of_used_cols)

cnt = 0
while cnt < 100:
    chnk = chnk_iter.get_chunk(_chunk_size)
    chnk.to_csv('first_output_specification', float_format='%.8f',
                columns=column_mapping['first_output_specification'],
                mode='a',
                header=True,
                index=False)
    # ..... do the same thing for the rest of the output specifications

    cnt += 1
```

**My problem** is that this is *really* slow. Each chunk takes about a minute to generate append to the CSV files for, and thus I'm looking at almost 2 hours for the task to complete.

I have tried to place a few optimizations by only using the union of the column subsets when reading in the CSV, as well as setting `na_filter=False`, but it still isn't acceptable.

I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this light processing of a CSV file in Python, either by means of an optimization or correction to my approach or perhaps simply there is a better tool suited for this kind of job then Pandas... to me (*an inexperienced Pandas user*) this looks like it is as fast as it could get with Pandas, but I may very well be mistaken.

Comment: Is it possible to switch to a database approach ? This is one big csv file !

Comment: @Jylo I really wish that were the case, but no.

Comment: Does `chunksize` contain the number of rows you want to have in each chunk?

Comment: @albert Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Could you do more than one chuck at a time ? With threads maybe

Comment: Which OS are you working on? Could you take a look at your system's performance (CPU load on each CPU, RAM, swap file) when performing chucking the file?

Comment: @pwnsauce I don't have much experience with multithreading, but I shall look into it. And albert I'm on Windows 7. The input/output format being CSV is something that has provided to me as a specification, I can't change it unfortunately. I will do that and update the question accordingly though.

Comment: Related thread with interesting info: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file

Comment: You're opening the file, reading the data into a DataFrame, chunking it and write it to another csv file. This takes a lot of memory since you have different "instances" of the same data. I am not sure since I am not working on Windows but I would try to split the file using OS-based operations with less overhead. Maybe using the PowerShell should give you the possibility to split files based on line numbers as shown [here](http://discoposse.com/2011/09/29/powershell-splitting-log-files/).

Comment: Does the order of the data in the target file need to be identical to that of the source file? In other words, is the line order important?

Comment: @Kristof Indeed it is, yes. And albert I will take a look into that as well, thanks. I'm aware there's a memory overhead here but I was sort of under the impression that it wasn't a big deal in this case, clearly I should do some more detailed benchmarking (as I'm doing now).

Comment: @albert It definitely looks like the bottleneck is writing to csv with `to_csv` : simply chunking the input into dataframes and doing nothing with them is extremely quick,. I've now found. So I'm not sure if the PowerShell file splitting would make any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you're getting any advantage from a Panda's dataframe, so it is just adding overhead.  Instead, you can use python's own [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) that is easy to use and nicely optimized in C.

Consider reading much larger chunks into memory (perhaps 10MB at a time), then writing-out each of the reformatted column subsets before advancing to the next chunk.  That way, the input file only gets read and parsed once.

One other approach you could try is to preprocess the data with the Unix [*cut*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command to extract only the relevant columns (so that Python doesn't have to create objects and allocate memory for data in the unused columns): `cut -d, -f1,3,5 somedata.csv`

Lastly, try running the code under [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) so that the CPU bound portion of your script gets optimized through their tracing JIT.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the python csv module and generators.

I've found generators much faster than other approaches for parsing huge server logs and such.

```
import csv

def reader(csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r') as f:
        csvreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
        for line in csvreader:
            yield line  # line is a tuple

def formatter(lines):
    for line in lines:
        # format line according to specs
        yield formatted_line

def write(lines, csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for line in lines:
            writer.writerow(line)

 lines = reader('myfile.in.csv')
 formatted_lines = formatter(lines)
 write(formatted_lines, 'myfile.out.csv')
```

This is just for reading a transforming a single input csv into a single output csv, but you could write the formatter and writer to output several files.

(I now see that this question is a month old - not sure if you've solved your problem already -  if not and if you want more detailed explanations/examples let me know.)

Answer (score 0):

CPU is faster than disk access. One trick is to gzip your file and read from that.

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('input.gz','r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print('got line', line)
```